# Unable to browse the web - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, connection, browser

I have this problem on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: whenever I open a new Chromium - Chrome - Firefox - Opera window to reach ANY website, it'll only show a "Please Update Internet Explorer" page - which I'm not using, being on ubuntu.

So how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It looks like your Router has been hacked!**

If you have another Internet device check if there are the same message if you are connecting over the same router.

These links could be usefull:

[Outdated Browser Detected, Update Internet Explorer Warning](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25826292?tstart=0#25826292?tstart=0)

[Safari says "Please Update Internet Explorer"](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25375704#25375704)

[How to manage a hacked wireless router](http://www.thesafemac.com/how-to-manage-a-hacked-wireless-router/)

[How to prevent your Linksys router from getting The Moon malware (official)](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&app=vw&vw=1&login=1&json=1&docid=56b6de2449fd497bb8d1354860f50b76_How_to_prevent_getting_The_Moon_malware.xml)

Answer (score 0):

May be that not all the required certs were downloaded on your computer.  Bring up terminal and type the following command to refresh your SSL certificates:

`$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`

Once you re-install the certs, restart your computer and try again.